# Laravel Storage: Have you ever use obs driver instead of s3 driver?

Tags: php, laravel, filesystems, huawei-developers

I'm using Laravel to update some images to a object storage service in Huawei Cloud. But i have this error when i use the driver OBS in filesystem. If i use the driver S3 (for aws s3) everything works fine...

***Symfony\Component\ErrorHandler\Error\FatalError
Declaration of Obs\Internal\Common\SdkCurlFactory::create(Psr\Http\Message\RequestInterface $request, array $options) must be compatible with GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlFactoryInterface::create(Psr\Http\Message\RequestInterface $request, array $options): GuzzleHttp\Handler\EasyHandle***

This is my code:

***$disk = Storage::disk('obs');***

Laravel version: 7.0
Php versión: 7.4.3

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Welcome to SO. Do you already check with this package: https://github.com/dscmall/laravel-filesystem-obs?

Comment: Yes!, mi code is based on that package. I follow all the steps but when i start to upload some file that error appears. The worst part is that I can't find any documentation about this :(

Comment: Try to add `composer require guzzlehttp/guzzle:^6.5` as dependency.  

Seems like you are using guzzle 7. This version has return type for `create` method. 

https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle/blob/6.5/src/Handler/CurlFactoryInterface.php - version 6.5 doesn't have return type.

Comment: @dduenas-niomads How did you solve this?

Comment: @DandyMandy the Dmytro's comment is the best way. Im going to make an answer

Answer (score 0):

The answer = composer require guzzlehttp/guzzle:^6.5
Thanks @Dmytro

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/29838830)